# Solving first order differential equation with integral term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Consider
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = \int_{0}^{\infty} y(x)dx. $$

I want to solve above differential equation. Can I consider right hand side as constant to solve this?

I know RHS is a constant but it also involves solution $y$, which might create trouble unless solution is known to us.

Also is it possible to find solution to given ordinary differential equation which is independent of $y$.

Comment: Do you have an expression for $p(x)$? I think I have an idea but I'm going to have to work it out to see if it works

Comment: No, $p(x)$ is any continuous function.

Comment: Ok. My idea was to start by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ to get rid of the integral and get a second-order linear equation, and then any solution to this equation must also solve that one, but with a general $p(x)$ that next equation isn't always going to be solvable. (in fact if $p$ isn't differentiable then my approach makes no sense whatsoever)

Comment: Interestingly I was able to show that if $p$ is constant then the solution must be uniquely zero. Not sure if that's helpful at all but it's something

Comment: For this I hope you are assuming that this differential equation has solution which is two times differentiable, but we may also get a solution which is only one time differentiable.

Comment: Yeah I missed that, good point. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in considering the right side first as a mostly independent constant. Then you can apply the integration formula
$$
y'+py=C\implies y(x)=y(0)e^{-P(x)}+C\int_0^xe^{P(s)-P(x)}ds.
$$

Now with this you can return to the original equation to try to determine $C$
$$
C=\int_0^\infty y(x)\,dx=y(0)\int_0^\infty e^{-P(x)}\,dx+C\int_0^\infty\int_0^xe^{P(s)-P(x)}ds\,dx
$$
Now if the integrals involved have finite values, and if then $C$ does not cancel from the equation, you can get a value for $C$ that in addition is proportional to $y(0)$ (as the linearity of the original equation demands).

Comment: Yeah, I got it.

Comment: When I take initial condition of the form $y(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)y(x)dx$, then I think it is not possible to find $y(0)$ and $C$ in such a way that $y(0)$ is independent of $C$ and vice versa.

Comment: @Mathnerd : The equation is linear homogeneous in $y$. The value of $y(0)$ has no influence on the solvability.

Comment: Thanks, but if $C$ cancel from the equation then what can we say?

Comment: @Mathnerd You can solve for $C$ and $y(0)$ independently, you obtain two linear equations in two unknowns. You can convert it into a matrix equation in $2$ dimensions and solve it.